# Python Click CLI Library - retry input prompt on validation error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) library to create a small CLI tool. At a certain point I prompt for a user's e-mail that is validated.

When the validation fails, the tool exits with an error code. Is there an option/functionality/method to let click retry asking a valid e-mail from the user? Could not find any reference to it in the manual.

Actually I want the same behaviour as the password prompt in the below example. When the two entered passwords are not the same, the password has to be re-entered again. Is it possible to enable this for any prompt?

```
def validate_email(ctx, param, value):
    if not re.match(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)", value):
        raise click.UsageError('Incorrect email address given')
    else:
        return value


@click.command()
@click.option('--email', prompt="E-mail address", callback=validate_email)
@click.option('--password', hide_input=True, confirmation_prompt=True)
def ask_email(email, password):
    click.echo('Valid Email: ' + email)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use a while loop in the ask_email function, and then put a specific return value for the validate email function (for when it is not valid), and exit the while loop if there is a valid answer (it doesn't return that specific value)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000. However when asking multiple options, an user would have to re-enter all the options again and again. I was hoping there would be some argument that can be given to the `option` function....

Answer (score 2):

If you catch your exception, you can prompt within the except block and then call your validation callback again (this will recursively loop until a valid entry is given):

```
def validate_email(ctx, param, value):
    try:
        if not re.match(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)",
                        value):
            raise ValueError(value)
        else:
            return value
    except ValueError, e:
        click.echo('Incorrect email address given: {}'.format(e))
        value = click.prompt(param.prompt)
        return validate_email(ctx, param, value)
```